# Problem while filtering by 'category_name'

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have the following code in order to display a custom WP_Query:

```
<ul>
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'preguntas', 
    'posts_per_page' => 50, 
    'category_name' => 'fianza'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" 
        rel="bookmark" 
        title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a><br>
    <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'tipos', 'categories: ', ' / ' ); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

However, when I add the `'category_name' => 'fianza'` argument, it does not display any results (and there is content in this category). I know it's a problem with the `category_name` because if I take it off, it will display all results without a problem.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks!

**Using var dump leads me to this**

`string(302) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_5zuqa4_posts.ID FROM wp_5zuqa4_posts WHERE 1=1 AND 0 = 1 AND wp_5zuqa4_posts.post_type = 'preguntas' AND (wp_5zuqa4_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_5zuqa4_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_5zuqa4_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_5zuqa4_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"`

Comment: Works when I test with known good values. Are you sure you have published content in that category and in that post type?

Comment: hi @s_ha_dum, thanks for your reply. Indeed there is content in that category. Maybe this category is not linked to my post type? How can I check this?

Comment: If there is content in the category it would have to be "linked" or you wouldn't have a way to assign the categories.

Comment: There is content... However I don't know how else to troubleshoot this :(

Comment: Put `var_dump($loop->request);` after your query and look at the SQL very carefully. What doesn't match?

Comment: I've updated the question with the var dump result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
WHERE 1=1 AND 0 = 1
```

Usually indicates a `meta_query` or `tax_query` failure, in you case, the latter. This doesn't mean there are no results it means ...

1. That the taxonomy doesn't exist. In this case, you are dealing with
   a Core taxonomy so this is unlikely.
2. The term is bad. This is a strong possibility. Make sure the term is
   correct and that you are using the ***slug*** and not the name,
   despite the parameter name.
3. The taxonomy is not valid for the chosen post type. You claim that
   there is content assigned to the term. In order for that to be true
   you would have to have registered the taxonomy to the post type.
   Still, I suspect that this is the problem.

Comment: Hi @s_ha_dum! That's totally correct. I was not using the proper term. Just as a reference, I used the "Custom Post Types" plugin to create the taxonomy. Later on I changed the taxonomy name and the plugin states: "Changing the name, after adding terms to the taxonomy, will not update the terms in the database" so that's why I was confused.